# Can ipyleaflet labels be displayed in Google Colab?

Tags: google-colab, ipyleaflet

I have plotted a simple interactive map with ipyleaflet using Google Colab as an environment for running the code, but I am struggling with adding labels to the places.

I can create labels that appear on clicking a place marker, but the labels are empty although the correct data are read from the GeoJSON file (cf. "print" statement in the code shared below):

[image]

This is the relevant section of my code:

```
# add labels for all places on map

from ipyleaflet import Map, Marker, Popup

# Create a map centered on a specific location
map = Map(center=(55, 7), zoom=3)

# print(data) # optional to check if GeoJSON file is read correctly

# Loop over the features and create a marker for each one
for feature in data['features']:
    # Get the coordinates and place name from the feature properties
    coords = feature['geometry']['coordinates']
    place_name = feature['properties']['City'] # double-check name of "place name" column
    print(place_name)

    # Create a marker with a popup
    marker = Marker(location=(coords[1], coords[0]))
    popup = Popup(
        location=(coords[1], coords[0]),
        close_button=False,
        auto_close=False,
        close_on_escape_key=False,
    )
    popup.children = [str(place_name)[:10]] # truncate place names
    print(popup.children)
    marker.popup = popup

    # Add the marker to the map
    map.add_layer(marker)

# Display the map
map'
```

Is this, perhaps, a known issue with Google Colab, or does my code need fixing?

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to fix this by using the `message` function according to the `ipyleaflet` documentation:

https://ipyleaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layers/popup.html

Here is the new code:

```
# add labels for all places on map

from ipyleaflet import Map, Marker, Popup
from ipywidgets import HTML

# Create a map centered on a specific location
map = Map(center=(55, 7), zoom=3)

# print(data) # optional to check if GeoJSON file is read correctly

# Loop over the features and create a marker for each one
for feature in data['features']:
    # Get the coordinates and place name from the feature properties
    coords = feature['geometry']['coordinates']
    place_name = feature['properties']['City'] # double-check name of "place name" column
    print(place_name)

    # Create a marker

    marker = Marker(location=(coords[1], coords[0]))

    # Create pop-up for each location
        
    popup = Popup(
        location=(coords[1], coords[0]),
        close_button=False,
        auto_close=False,
        close_on_escape_key=False,
    )
    popup.children = str(place_name)[:10] # truncate place names
    print(popup.children)
    message= HTML()
    message.value = popup.children
    marker.popup = message

    # Add the marker to the map
    map.add_layer(marker)

# Display the map
map
```